# find the number of occurrence

Tags: excel

apple

berry

berry

coconut

coconut

coconut

donut

donut

grape

lime

Hi all, above is my sample data. How can I count the number of occurrence? 
My desired outcome should be something like:

apple 1

berry 2

coconut 3

donut 2

grape 1

lime 1

I have tried =COUNTIF($A:$A,A7) but is not what I want to achieve.
Please guide. Thank You.

Comment: Google PivotTables. And in future please ask this sort of question on SuperUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use   **=COUNTIF(A1:A19,A*)** formula

according to column value you change **A*** value.

```
For example

two column A and B with row number. inset formula in B column of front of each fruits.  


--  A     -------------------B------

1 apple        =COUNTIF(A1:A5,A1)

2 berry        =COUNTIF(A1:A5,A2)

3 berry        =COUNTIF(A1:A5,A3)   

4 coconut      =COUNTIF(A1:A5,A4)  

5 coconut      =COUNTIF(A1:A5,A5)
```